# Can't see infinite loop

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, web-crawler, urllib3

I am trying to write a webcrawler but I am stuck because I cant see infinite loop somewhere in my code.

```
class Crawler(object):
    def __init__(self, url, query, dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)):
        self.start_url = url
        self.start_parsed = urllib3.util.parse_url(url)
        self.query = re.compile(query, re.IGNORECASE)
        self.dir = dir
        self.__horizon = set()
        self.log = []

        self.__horizon.add(url)
        self.log.append(url)
        print("initializing crawler....")
        print(locals())

    def start(self, depth= 5, url = '/'):
        print(url, depth)
        self.log.append(url)
        if depth > 0:
            pool = urllib3.PoolManager()
            data = pool.request("GET", self.start_url if url == '/' else url).data.decode('utf-8')

            valid_list = []
            self.add_horizon(parser_soup.get_links(data), valid_list)

            if re.search(self.query, parser_soup.get_text(data)):
                self.output(data)

            for u in valid_list:
                self.start(depth = (depth-1), url = u)

    def output(self, data):
        with open(os.path.join(self.dir, get_top_domain(self.start_parsed.host) + '.' + str(time.time()) + '.html'), 'w+') as f:
            f.write(data)

    def add_horizon(self, url_list, valid_list = []):
        for url in url_list:
            if get_top_domain(url) == get_top_domain(self.start_parsed.host)  \
                    and (not str(url) in self.log or not str(url) in self.__horizon):
                valid_list.append(str(url))

        self.__horizon.update(valid_list)
```

It runs forever. How should I ensure that I eliminate duplicate links?

Comment: what do you mean "can't see infinite loop?"

Comment: @ uoɥʇʎPʎzɐɹC He doesn't understand why his code is running into an infinite loop.

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but one suggestion: Make the PoolManager in `__init__` and use it throughout to get the most benefit out of it.

Comment: There probably is no infinite loop, the program simply runs for a very long time. A rough calculation: If each crawled page contains 20 links (a low estimate for most web sites), you have to load 20^4=160K pages. At 10ms per page, that would take over 4 hours. At 40 links per page, it would take about 70 hours. And so on. Exponential growth. What happens when you set default depth to 1 instead of 5?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adapted from Giogian's code:

```
class Crawler(object):
    def __init__(self, url, query, dir=os.path.dirname(__file__)):
        self.visited = set()
        # Rest of code...

    def start(self, depth=5, url='/'):
        if url in self.visited:
            return True
        self.visited.add(url)
```

`defaultdict` is a dictionary that has a default which is used if the index doesn't exist. This however, is the wrong solution. A set would be more memory efficient and elegant, as shown in my code.

A set uses O(1) time - just as fast as @Giorgian's answer.

Use `Ctrl-C` to interrupt your program when it's in an infinite loop. This will print a Traceback showing the command that was being executed when the program was interrupted. Do this a few times and you should get a good idea of where it happens. Alternatively, use a debugger and pause when it's in the infinite loop and use the "step" feature to run to the next line of execution so you can follow the program's execution. PyCharm is a great editor that includes a debugger. It has good autocompletion and is just good all-around. It's free, check it out.

Comment: defaultdict is the wrong solution! Checking if a value is in a list takes O(n) time while using a defaultdict takes only O(1) time!

Comment: @ uoɥʇʎPʎzɐɹC Use a set if you want to use the `in` idiom.

Comment: @ uoɥʇʎPʎzɐɹC At the very least, could you remove the downvote from my answer, as your code is basically a copy-paste my answer? The only difference is that you used `set()`, which was my suggestion anyway!

Comment: @GiorgianBorca-Tasciuc I came up with it myself. Didn't see your comment. Removed the downvote. Okay?

Comment: @GiorgianBorca-Tasciuc and I have the debugger suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

Add a `visited` property inside your crawler.

```
from collections import defaultdict
class Crawler:
    def __init__(self, url, query, dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)):
        self.visited = defaultdict(bool)
        # Rest of code...

    def start(self, depth= 5, url = '/'):
        if self.visited[url]:
            return True
        self.visited[url] = True
        # Rest of code...
```

To be honest though, I can't see the infinite loop either. It would help if you posted some output.

EDIT: Note that in above answer I wrote that using a `defaultdict` is the wrong solution. I meant to say that using a *list* is the wrong solution!

EDIT 2: @Jona Christopher Sahnwald made a point more valid than mine (see his comment under the OP's question). It might be more productive to add a `max_visit` and `current_visit` property in your class (set to like 1000 or so). Start with `current_visit` at 0, and every time you visit a site, increment `current_visit`. When `current_visit` is greater than `max_visit`, abort the crawl. Note that instead of using recursion to recurse over visited web sites, it might be better to implement some kind of stack so you can pause/resume the crawl rather than aborting. Like so:

```
from collections import defaultdict

class Crawler:
    def __init__(self, url, query, dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)):
        self.visited = defaultdict(bool)
        self.current_visit = 0
        self.max_visit = 1000
        self.to_visit = []
        # Rest of code...

    def start(self, depth=5, url = '/'):
        self.to_visit.append((url, 1))
        while len(self.to_visit) > 0:
            url, current_depth = self.to_visit.pop()
            if current_depth > depth:
                continue
            elif visited[url]:
                continue
            elif self.current_visited > self.max_visited:
                break

            self.current_visited += 1
            visited[url] = True

            # Code that does something for each page (like download it, etc)

            # Code that finds links on page...

            for link in links_on_page:
                self.to_visit.append((link, current_depth + 1))
```

That way, you can pause the crawl once `current_visit` exceeds `max_visit`, allowing you to crawl in batches of `max_visit`.

Comment: @ uoɥʇʎPʎzɐɹC Well it's not complete of course! It's only meant to guide to OP.

Comment: see my answer, a list is much better

Comment: doesn't conform with PEP 8 either